# <div> onClick run javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have the following html code

```
<div id="userMenu">
  <ul>
    <li id="tab1">
      <div onclick="displayTab(1);" class="tab">Transaction History</div>
    </li>
    <li id="tab2">
      <div onClick="displayTab(2)" class="tab">Top Up</div>
    </li>
    <li id="tab3">
      <div onclick="displayTab(3);" class="tab">Profile</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div style="clear: both; margin: 15px; border: 2px solid #99ffff;">
  <div id="content1" class="tabContent">
    Content1
  </div>
  <div id="content2" class="tabContent" style="display: none;">
    Content2
  </div>
  <div id="content3" class="tabContent" style="display: none;">
    Content3
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
function displayTab(tabNo){ alert(tabNo);
  for(i = 1; i < 4; i++){
    document.getElementById('content'+i).style.display = 'none';
  } 
  document.getElementById('content'+tabNo).style.display= 'block';
}
```

Why is it that the function displayTab cannot be activated? If I change the onclick with `onclick="alert('1')"`, it worked. I tried on Opera and Firefox, both resulting the same. Error console tells me that there's a

> ReferenceError: Undefined variable displayTab

Do note that that is not the full code. Even crazier fact is that if I use that code (the one I put here) as is, it worked and no error in Error Console. Help, anyone?

Comment: Can you show where the function is defined? That is, is it linked from an external file? Is it in an inline script? First make sure it's loaded at all (e.g. by adding "alert('loaded')") after the closing brace of the displayTab() function.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EZBL5/ works

Comment: As Vlad said above, it is almost certain that you are incorrectly defining the function....

Comment: Found the cause guys. Sorry to bother and thanks for trying to help. I declared that as inline script.

Comment: You should check the debug console to what cause this error.
IF you test on Google Chrome, the shortcut is Ctrl + Shift + J

Comment: If your current snippet works as it is then you might have javascript error in your page somewhere else,possibly before the definition of `displayTab` function. Try removing other scripts or move definition of `displayTab` on top most script block.Check with javascript console for other errors if any.I can't say much without watching your full code.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
onClick="javascript:displayTab(1)"
```

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short. Would you mind adding some text to explain how this code answers the question?